# A (trigonometric ?) cryptography riddle

Tags: cipher

> **Tan**: Why did *sin* eat a sandwich?
>
> **Cot**: Just *cos*!

After seeing this small "joke" made by **Tan** and **Cot**, **Sin** replied:

"Well, I have something better than jokes: ***riddles***! Can you solve this one?"

**tzexwx xzy mjb wn ol agl dluDa dphxyZgrgy ti**

**Tan** then said "That seems like a terrible riddle. I'll still solve it though."

Shortly after 7 minutes of thinking, **Cot** said "Can you at least give us a hint?"

**Sin** replied:

> Think this: A fruit left to ___ for almost 2 weeks (but 1 day less) and reversed; French and German; **K3**, but **not K1 and K2** (and certainly not K4). Look for the significant, emphasized word that is the least related to the **"others"**.

Can you help **Tan** and **Cot** out?

Comment: Ok, so I'm not great at this sort of puzzle, and don't know much about cryptography, but some ideas that might help someone else to solve. Stop reading now if you don't want to be either hinted or misled (I don't know which) by my ramblings. 1. There appear to be 9 words in the cyphertext, so it could be a sohcahtoa mnemonic. 2. '13' reversed is 31, or 2^5-1, which may hint at base-32 encoding. 3. A fruit may be left to *rot* - short for rotate, and 13 *minutes* is an angle. Not much I know, but may help someone :)

Comment: Pretty sure you're right about the fruit but that the 13 combines with it to make [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13).

Comment: Er, sorry, to be clearer, the 13 that combines with it is the "two weeks but one day less". The 13 in the question may have some other significance.

Comment: The message is a "comeback" or response to the starting joke

Comment: @jhabbot Actually, besides the trig ratio names and the starting joke, there is no relation to trignometry afterwards. You're close for the decryption methods though :)

Comment: I just changed the question a little bit to make it easier to solve. The "13 minutes" is now "7 minutes". This change does not make it harder to solve the puzzle and doesn't change the steps required and the solution in any way.

Comment: Do you mean that the 7 is a hint in some way that the 13 wasn't before?

Comment: Yes, the 7 is a hint. However the 13 wasnt before; it was just a random time which I didn't realize made the puzzle more confusing until later.

Answer (score 4):

## Partial Answer:

Based on Sin's hints, I would think this would the meaning behind each part:

- A fruit left to ___ for almost 2 weeks (but 1 day less) = **ROT13**
- Reversed = **Atbash**, since it basically reverses the alphabet
- German = **Ubchi** or **Enigma**. These 2 make logical sense, as they were both used by the Germans in WWI and WWII. I think **Ubchi** makes more sense, as Sin stated in his hint to think French and German, and the French cracked **Ubchi** in WWI.
- French = **Vigenere Cipher**
- K3 = The third part of the **Kryptos** statue (?). It says certainly not **K4**, since the 4th part of the statue hasn't been cracked yet. I'm still not sure about this though.

---

Key for **Vigenere** and **Ubchi** =

> **riddles**

This is largely due to the OP bolding the word **others** in Sin's hint. This referred to bold words as the others, and the only **bold** word that is also *italicized* is the previously mentioned word.

Comment: German = Enigma

Comment: We seem rather short of key material if there's a Vigenere and an Enigma in there...

Comment: @icecream.sandwich You are on the right track!